# Combine Create and DetailView in django

Tags: python, django-views

I have a model Book and a model Review (with a ForeignKey to Book). I wanted to create a view where you have all the data related to a book (DetailView), and add the functionality of showing and creating reviews. I came up with this code, but don't know whether it is a good practice, maybe I should go for something different:

```html
class BookDetailView(CreateView):
 template_name = 'books/book_detail.html'
 form_class = ReviewForm

 def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
  context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

  slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
  obj = Book.objects.get(slug__iexact=slug)

  if get_language() == 'es':
   context['reviews'] = obj.review_set.all().filter(language__iexact='es')
  else:
   context['reviews'] = obj.review_set.all().filter(language__iexact='en')

  if len(context['reviews']) == 0:
   context['is_empty'] = True

  context['object'] = obj
  return context

 def form_valid(self, form):
  obj = form.save(commit=False)

  return super().form_valid(form)
```

And the template:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}

<h1>{{object.title}}</h1>

<h2>{% trans "Reviews section" %}</h2>

{% for review in reviews %}
<b>{{review.title}}

{% endfor %}

<h2>Add a review!</h2>
{% include "form.html" with form=form %}

{% endblock content %}
```

And finally the url: url(r'^(?P[\w-]+)/$', ...)

What do you think?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Don't add is_empty to the context, use empty in your for loop `{% for obj in objects %}{{ obj }}{% empty %}No objects{% endfor %}` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty

Comment: You can also use an normal django.views.generic.DetailView for the book instance and define a post method to handle the post data with the ResponseForm. In that case you should add the ResponseForm to the context as well. I think this way is a little more obvious which object you are creating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did something similar once. But used the DetailView and just added the ReviewForm to the context and added a method to handle post data. Something like this:

```
class BookDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Book

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        language = get_language()
        ctx.update({
            'reviews': ctx['book'].review_set.all().filter(language__iexact=language),
            'form': ReviewForm()
        })
        return ctx

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object(self.get_queryset())
        form = ReviewForm(self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.book = self.object
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.object.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            ctx = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
            ctx.update({'form': form})
            return self.render_to_response(ctx)
```

I guess this takes a little more code for handling the form, but the bonus is you can set the related book (the user can't fiddle with that form data).

Note that you don't have to specify `template_name` because it is automagical correct.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my question and helped me get rid of a bug xd.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a little bit old but it helps me a lot with my issue. Thank you @allcaps

First of all, I would like to mention that the "ReviewForm" should inherit from forms.ModelForm and than we will have a access to "instance" and "save()"

More about ModelForm you can read in django docs [Django ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)